# How to convert vector from 1-row table in R

Tags: r, vector, row

In R, I have a 1-row table. How do I convert that to a vector?

Specifically, the table is this:

```
 0  1  2  3  4 
21 35 46 62 36
```

I've tried bracket notation but to no avail!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or you could use `as.vector(x)`

Answer (score 5):

It already is a vector.

```
tbl <- table(rpois(100, 10))
tbl[1]
tbl[2:5]
tbl[tbl > 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the table is named x, then just use c(x).

Comment: This is bad style - you shouldn't use `c()` for the side effect of stripping attributes.  Be explicit and use `as.vector()`